# Google Chrome can't connect to localhost

Tags: php, google-chrome, netbeans

I'm trying to follow a tutorial for my first php project in netbeans. I select new php application name it and then simply type `echo("anything")` in the php portion of index.php and when I run it I always get the error Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to localhost. I don't understand why because I also have a Java web application(selection from netbeans) and when I put stuff in the html I can get things to run just fine. How can I get rid of this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that PHP is running on your machine (XAMP or WAMP) and it should be `echo "anything";`

Comment: Is that something that is included in the PHP download, or will I have to download that separately?

Comment: no, you need to download XAMPP or WAMP separately. 
https://www.apachefriends.org/
http://www.wampserver.com/

Download one of these. Start the server and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

PHP requires that the PHP parser is running on a server. The error comes from a lack of this. HTML requires no parser so it can be sent as is. The java web application may have a module to enable PHP, and you likely need to either enable it or tell it where a PHP binary is; if not both.

Alternatively, you can use XAMPP/MAMPP to host the server; just make sure it is not running on the same port as your java host.

You can get XAMPP/MAMPP here:
[www.apachefriends.org](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html)