# Can't connect to localhost using Chrome with Uniform Server

Tags: php, html, web-applications, localhost, server-side-scripting

I'm trying to run a .php web application on Google Chrome, using Uniform Server. I thought that just having that installed would make PHP run, but clearly there's a lot I don't know. First off, when I opened the file from `file:///C:/Users/...` etc the PHP didn't execute properly. Here's the code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        Hello to you, good sir.
        <?php
            echo "</br> Hello there yourself.";
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's the output on the website:

```
Hello to you, good sir. Hello there yourself."; ?>
```

And here's how the `<body>` code looks from Chrome:

```
Hello to you, good sir.
<!--?php
    echo "</br-->
Hello there yourself.";
```

Then, when I tried accessing the file from localhost, Chrome wouldn't even connect, saying:

```
Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to localhost
```

I'm aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23157692/google-chrome-cant-connect-to-localhost), but the OP didn't appear to have software needed to run PHP. I'm pretty sure I have the right software, but I don't know how to use it. How do I get Uniform Server to run PHP, and how do I connect to localhost from Chrome?

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you didn't mock me; I'm new to PHP, scripting, and server-side scripting. A push in the right direction would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP wont work if opened directly in browser, thats not how PHP works, it needs to be run through the PHP parser.

### A Step by step:

1. Download the Latest package
2. Unpack it onto desktop or `C:`, (somewhere your find it)
3. Open up the `UniServerZ` folder, where you unpacked it
4. Double click `UniController.exe`
5. Click Start Apache button - it should go green like below

[image]

5. Remove the junk files in `UniServerZ/www`
6. Put your PHP files inside that `www` folder.
7. Visit `http://localhost` to view your PHP files

Comment: Brilliant, one question: which are the junk files? Do I not need the css folder, the images folder, or any of the other files?

Comment: You dont need any of the files its just the landing page and info for UniServer, what goes in www is your stuff. www is the webroot